# Google Tag Manager in IFrame on different domains

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

We have two main web sites and payment system that runs from IFrame for first or second sites. Payments system is on different domain than main sites.
Business requirement was to implement separate Google Tag Manager IDs for main systems, and now I need to monitor payment system that runs in IFrame on different domain, in a way that data would belong to main system.
If payment system would run on same domain as main systems I could use dataLayer.push() by declaring global dataLayer variable on both main pages, and then using it like parent.dataLayer... 
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide

Question: How to use Google Tag Manager to monitor activity in an IFrame by reusing tag ID of parent page.

Comment: Do all three sites use GTM (site1.com site2.com paymentsite.com)? Do they all use the same Universal Analytics ID?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the same GTM code on both of these sites and then use the Cross-domain features in standard page view Tag